# Como adicionar barra de rolagem em DataGridView VB?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Necessito adicionar uma barra de rolagem para a quantidade de linhas em um `DataGridView`, pois não quero trabalhar com paginação, aí surge a questão, como fazer?

Comment: Você está fazendo um WinForm?

Comment: Sim, coloquei um dataGridView em um Form, preencho este, porém os dados do banco ultrapassam o tamanho do mesmo, necessitando assim de um Scroll.

Answer (score 0):

O scroll do `datagridview` aparece quando ele está com registros que não cabem mais na tela.

Cria um formulário novo e adiciona um novo `datagridview`

Coloca esse código no load.

```
string[] row0 = { "11/22/1968", "29", "Revolution 9",
            "Beatles", "The Beatles [White Album]" };
            dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 5;

            dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Navy;
            dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
            dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font =
                new Font(dataGridView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);

            dataGridView1.Location = new Point(8, 8);
            dataGridView1.Size = new Size(500, 250);
            dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode =
                DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders;
            dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersBorderStyle =
                DataGridViewHeaderBorderStyle.Single;
            dataGridView1.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.Single;
            dataGridView1.GridColor = Color.Black;
            dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;

            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Release Date";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Track";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Title";
            dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "Artist";
            dataGridView1.Columns[4].Name = "Album";
            dataGridView1.Columns[4].DefaultCellStyle.Font =
                new Font(dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Italic);

            dataGridView1.SelectionMode =
                DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
            dataGridView1.MultiSelect = false;
            dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            //songsDataGridView.CellFormatting += new
            //    DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(
            //    songsDataGridView_CellFormatting);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row0);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row0);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row0);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row0);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row0);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row0);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row0);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row0);

            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row0);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row0);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row0);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row0);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row0);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row0);



            dataGridView1.Columns[0].DisplayIndex = 3;
```

Manda rodar e reduz o tamanho do `form`. Fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora aumenta o tamanho do `form`. Fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o comportamento padrão do componente.

Tenta converter o código para vb, vai funcionar da mesma forma.

Comment: Poderia me falar, em qual linha de código, especificamente se define o scroll, porque não consegui ver.

Comment: Nenhuma delas, por padrão ele já tem o scroll, o que deve estar acontecendo é que você deve ter configurado alguma coisa que desabilitou. Da uma lida aqui que ele fala de algumas coisas que podem tirar o scroll. Não vou estar no computador por agora. Se não ajudar me fala aqui que depois eu testo elas. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10833212/3517631